# Use of Cantor Schroder-Bernstein theorem?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Use the Schröder-Bernstein theorem to show that there is a bijection between two intervals $[0,1]\subseteq \Bbb R$ and $[1,\infty)\subseteq \Bbb R$, thus they have the same cardinality.
>
> What about the sets $(0,5)$ and $(10,20)$? Is there a bijection between them? (Don't need the Schröder-Bernstein theorem here). Similarly, consider $[0,\infty)$ and $[1,\infty)$.

Hello, this is a question from my practice final. Can anyone explain how to answer this question? As I understand, the theorem allows you to find a one-to-one function between two intervals to show that they have same cardinality, but I don't know how to apply this. For example, for the first question, is it simple as a function like $f(x) = 1/x$ or is there something more than that?

Comment: $f(x)=1/x$ doesn't work since it's not defined at $0$.  You need a one-to-one function that maps the entire interval $[0,1]$ into $[1,\infty)$.  Try $f(x)=x+1$.

Comment: Why don't you try reading the theorem? It doesn't say anything about intervals--it's much more general than that.

Comment: @vadim123 : $f(x)=1/x$ is a one-to-one function from $[1,\infty)$ to $[0,1]$.  I'm guessing that's what the OP meant. Of course, you need an injection going the other way.

Comment: So the first question has two answers ? One to go from [0,1] to [1, infinity] and another one from [1, infinity] to [0,1] ? f(x) = x + 1 , and f(x) = 1 / x respectively ?

Comment: @GdgamesGamers : yes, to apply the CSB Theorem you need two injections, one going in each direction, and you should not give them the same name.

Answer (score 4):

The Cantor-Bernstein theorem is probably one of the most useful and easily applied theorems in set theory.

> **Theorem.** If there exists an injection $f\colon A\to B$ and an injection $g\colon B\to A$ then there exists a bijection $h\colon A\to B$.

That is all. Under the axiom of choice we can replace the injections with surjections, or so, but still constructing injections is often simple enough, especially at the level of this question.

So to use the theorem you really just need to come up with two injections $f\colon[0,1]\to[1,\infty)$ and $g\colon[1,\infty)\to[0,1]$. This will be sufficient to conclude that there is a bijection between these two subsets of $\Bbb R$.